# Sanitize custom checkout fields data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, sanitization

Following the WooCommerce checkout fields customization docs:
[Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

I have added a custom field to woocommerce checkout page, through **functions.php**.

I'm worried if I have to sanitize user input for that custom field?

I think it doesn't need sanitization since it's passed into billing fields as in:  $fields['billing'], is that correct?

If not how do I sanitize this custom field?

Creating this custom field is meant to accept text strings(latin) and integers combined no longer than 50 in length.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

//Adding custom text field  
 $fields['billing']['billing_username'] = array(
'type' => 'text',
'label'     => __('Your Username', 'woocommerce'),
'placeholder'   => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
'required'  => true,
'class'     => array('form-row-first'),
'clear'     => true
 );

 return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look to the related Official Documentation linked in your question, you've got this snippet:

```
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

> **In your case you don't need that as address fields are already processed by Woocommerce.**
>
> **For custom special fields: The answer is yes** *(which is not your case)*
>
> As you can see in this code they use [**`sanitize_text_field()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) WordPress function, when saving the submitted data to database with [**`update_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) function…
>
> **This is only for custom checkout fields and not for existing checkout fields**, that already get their own process…

Comment: I understand although I followed "Adding Custom shipping and billing fields" section in the docs, not following the section "Adding a custom special field"

Comment: @t0r I have updated my answer… In your case for address fields you don't to sanitize data, as it's already be processed by WooCommerce core scripts…